# java proxy authentication IOException not being thrown

Tags: java, authentication, error-handling, proxy, ioexception

I am trying to connect to a proxy server but not supply any credentials so I can catch the 407 and tell the user they need to supply creds.

I cannot catch this error for the life of me.

```
    Socket socket = null;
    InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
    try
        {
            socket = new Socket(proxy);
            socket.connect(addr, getUrlConnectTimeout());
        }
     catch (IOException ioe)
       {
        logger.info("IOE");
        }
```

When I step though the code it brings me to the internal error "should not reach hear".  Within HttpConnectionSocketImpl.class

```
  private void doTunneling(HttpURLConnection conn) {
    try {
        doTunneling.invoke(conn);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException x) {
        throw new InternalError("Should not reach here", x);
    }
 }
```

The stack trace indicates an Io exception and indicates that auth is required.

I just don't understand why my try catch block is not catching this exception when the connection attempt is being made.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )"
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2084)
    ... 19 more

Answer (score 1):

doTunneling.invoke throws a InvocationTargetException (which is a ReflectiveOperationException ) and so

```
  throw new InternalError
```

is executed.

InternalError is an Error and so your

```
  catch (IOException
```

does no catch it.

As workaround you can use
      catch (Error e)
but that is not a good idea.

I think it is a bug in

```
java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection)
```

where signature should be extended with throws IOException and

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.getTargetException()
```

should be thrown in case it is an IOException 
(e.g. java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required")

Replace the single line

socket.connect(addr, getUrlConnectTimeout());

with

```
        try {
            socket.connect(addr, getUrlConnectTimeout());
        } catch (Error e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof InvocationTargetException) {
                InvocationTargetException tempInvocationTargetException = (InvocationTargetException)e.getCause();
                if (tempInvocationTargetException.getTargetException() instanceof IOException) {
                    // Extract the original IOException, see
                    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921296/java-proxy-authentication-ioexception-not-being-thrown/
                    throw (IOException)tempInvocationTargetException.getTargetException();
                }
            }
            // rethrow the original error
            throw e;
        }
```

should give the expected IOException.

Comment: I submitted a Bug for that. 

"We will review your report and have assigned it an internal review ID : 9047150"

Answer (score 0):

The bug has been accepted and will be resolved in later versions of JDK. Please see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173620

Comment: This is a long time later, but I've been trying to figure out which version of JDK8 the bug fix occurred in and I've failed to do so. Would you happen to know?